# Is it possible to iterate between two specific objects?

Tags: linq, loops

Suppose I have a list:-

```
var animals = new[] {"ant", "bear", "bee", ...... "monkey", ...... "zebra"};
```

what is the easiest way to iterate between bee and monkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much gnashing of teeth, hair pulling and banging my head against the wall, I decided to do it the easy way of creating my own iterator.

```
public static class LinqExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> InRange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, T first, T last) {
        int i = 0;

        while (list.Count() > i && ! list.ElementAt(i).Equals(first))
            ++i;

        while (list.Count() > i && ! list.ElementAt(i).Equals(last))
            yield return list.ElementAt(i);

        if (list.Count() > i && list.ElementAt(i).Equals(last))
            yield return list.ElementAt(i);
     }
}
```

now the following works perfectly:-

```
foreach (var x in animals.InRange("bee", "monkey")) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`SkipWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile.aspx) and [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile.aspx) extension methods

```
var myAnimals = animals.SkipWhile(a => a != "bee").TakeWhile(a => a != "monkey").ToList();
```

Comment: Note that this will exclude `monkey`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek if they're sorted alphabetically... *TakeWhile(a => a <= "monkey")*